# How do I iterate a table according to time intervals in Postgres?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

I want to obtain all rows in the table for each interval of 48h in a given period of time, in order to perform some statements.
In particular I want to retrieve all chart-times corresponding to the the measurements in LAB and whenever the IF clause is true, to create a flag for it.

This is what I did so far.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  i record;
  CHARTTIME TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM schema.lab L 
            JOIN schema.icu I ON L.ID = I.ID
            WHERE L.ITEM = 50912 AND 
            L.CHARTTIME < I.INTIME AND L.CHARTTIME > (I.INTIME - INTERVAL '7 DAY')  
  LOOP
    CHARTTIME := L.CHARTTIME;
    FOREACH CHARTTIME IN ARRAY CHARTTIME + INTERVAL '48 HOUR' 
    LOOP
         IF L.VALUENUM > L.VALUENUM + 0.3 THEN 
            '1'::INTEGER AS FLAG
         ELSEIF L.VALUENUM < L.VALUENUM + 0.3 THEN 
            '0'::INTEGER AS FLAG
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
;
```

Here I have two tables, one for LAB and one for ICU. In LAB I have the *item's codes*, the *chart time*, the *valuenum* of the measurement and the *id*. In ICU I also have the *id* and the *intime* (timestamp) corresponding to the arrival in icu.

I get a **syntax error**. I do not know if this approach is correct, though.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'1'"
LINE 16:     '1'::INTEGER AS AKI_FLAG
             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 442
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I want to retrieve all the columns ID,ITEM,CHARTTIME,VALUENUM,FLAG satisfying the code implemented. I am looking for item = 50912 corresponding to the creatinine value in MIMIC-III db. I have to look if there's an increasing value of 0.3 mg/dL every 48h before the patient enters the ICU.

Comment: . . "satisfying the code implemented" is not a very good description of a problem for a *human*.

Comment: @schr - Hello, can you add some sample data and expected output in table format. If you do that, question will be clear for us and we'll be able to help you fast. :)

Comment: I don't think you need a cursor/loop.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, it's the first time asking questions here. I re-asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861703/how-do-i-iterate-a-table-according-to-fixed-time-intervals-in-postgres#comment114676135_64861703 and I hope it's more clear. Thank you so much!